# Missing document in Elasticsearch when using BulkProcessor

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I'm using a `[java] kafka-producer` to push data to kafka-topic *x* and a `[java] high level consumer/bulkProcessor` to read from topic *x* and index data to elasticsearch. The producer pushes 10 docs each time. When I start my java code for bulkProcessor for the first time after running producer, I see only 9 records being pushed to ES, all with `"_version": 1`. The 10th record is not in ES.

But somehow, `beforeBulk()` and `afterBulk()` methods show the follwoing results.

```
Going to execute new bulk composed of 10 actions
Executed bulk composed of 10 actions
```

This moment onwards, if I remove the elasticsearch index and use the producer, I see 10 records consistently. I have no idea why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Note: ES version 2.2.0
Kafka: 0.9.0.0

**EDIT [Added relevant code]**

```
public Consumer(KafkaStream a_stream, int a_threadNumber, String esHost, String esCluster, int bulkSize, String topic) {

/*Create transport client*/
BulkProcessor bulkProcessor;

this.bulkProcessor = BulkProcessor.builder(client, new BulkProcessor.Listener() {
    public void beforeBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request) {
            System.out.format("Going to execute new bulk composed of %d actions\n", request.numberOfActions());
    }

    public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, BulkResponse response) {
            System.out.format("Executed bulk composed of %d actions\n", response.getItems().length);
    }

    public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, Throwable failure) {
            System.out.format("Error executing bulk", failure);
    }
    }).setBulkActions(bulkSize) 
            .setBulkSize(new ByteSizeValue(200, ByteSizeUnit.MB)) 
            .setFlushInterval(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(1))
            .build();
}

public void run() {     
    ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();   
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        byte[] x = it.next().message();
        try {           
            bulkProcessor.add(new IndexRequest(index, type, id.toString()).source(modifyMsg(x).toString()));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("bulkProcessor failed: " + m_threadNumber + e.getMessage());
        }                   
    }
    logger.info("Shutting down Thread: " + m_threadNumber);
}
```

Docs going to ES are of the following form:

```
{"index":"temp1","type":"temp2","id":"0","event":"we're doomed"}
{"index":"temp1","type":"temp2","id":"1","event":"we're doomed"}
{"index":"temp1","type":"temp2","id":"2","event":"we're doomed"}
...
{"index":"temp1","type":"temp2","id":"9","event":"we're doomed"}
```

**[EDIT]**

If I add the following line in my run() method the problem is gone.

```
public void run() {
    ...
    bulkProcessor.add(new IndexRequest(""));  //Added this line
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ...         
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that two documents pushed by your producer don't have the same ID?

Comment: Yes, I'm using doc-id `0-9`. The doc with id 9 is not getting indexed for the first time.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from your bulkProcessor?

Comment: I've added the code. I'm using only one thread for the topic. So only one object of type `Consumer` is being created.

Comment: In `id.toString()`, where does `id` come from?

Comment: id is a field in kafka message. My producer produces 10 docs in kafka with id varying from 0-9. I've already extracted and copied all relevant fields into the consumer class variables. I've seen all of `index`, `type`, `id.toString()` are parsed correctly

Comment: I don't think you can copy the message fields into class variables of your consumer, it doesn't make sense, even if you have a single thread, it doesn't feel right. Can you show the 10 messages that your bulkProcessor is sending?

Comment: Please update your question with all ten docs you're sending.

Comment: You said the ids varied from 0 to 9, but in your sample docs I see 1 to 10. Typos? Can you print out each document you're giving to your bulkprocessor instead of making them up?

Comment: Updated. My point is all the docs are valid json. I'm only concerned about the first three fields, which are correctly pushed to ES.

Comment: Is it always the last doc with id 9 that doesn't make it to ES?

Comment: Yes, consistently.

Comment: Are you certain that the thread is not terminated before the bulkprocessor gets a chance to send all documents?

Comment: Yes, the thread literally has a while(1) loop.

Comment: Can you print out what `response.getItems()` contains?

Comment: response.getItems().toString() returns `[Lorg.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkItemResponse;@a396840`

Comment: Yeah, well, you probably need to iterate over each item and print out its content :)

Comment: Looks like 1st operation is failing. It says `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0`

Comment: I think using "0" as id is not a wise idea as it might be ignored. Can you try to add +1 to each id so you have 1-10 instead of 0-9 ?

Comment: I've disabled the id for bulkProcessor and tried using ES auto-generated id, same problem persists.

Comment: You also get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Yes, the same error comes here.

Comment: After running the Kafka consumer, can you try going to your index and running `_refresh` (`POST /myindex/_refresh`)? Then check the number of documents (`GET /myindex/_search?size=0`).

Comment: size = 9 for 10 docs pushed for the first time. I was using elasticsearch head plugin before, so I guess it wouldn't have made any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like such a fool. In the line `bulkProcessor.add(new IndexRequest(index, type, id.toString()).source(modifyMsg(x).toString()));` the method `modifyMsg()` was initializing  `index`, `type` and `id`, which was set to empty string in the constructor. That's why my first index request was failing as it had invalid index name.